# Elasticsearch free storage space drastical reduce

Tags: elasticsearch

I executed a `update_by_query` to copy value from a field to another field that target ~80 million documents. I hosted Elasticsearch on AWS. During execution, I monitored the metrics and found an interesting problem.

During the execution, I saw drastically decline graph for free storage space and it went up back after the execution is finished.

[image]

What was happened during that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Concerning `FreeStorageSpace`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/es-metricscollected.html) here is what AWS says:

> The free space, in megabytes, for nodes in the cluster. Sum shows total free space for the cluster. Minimum, Maximum, and Average show free space for individual nodes. Amazon ES throws a ClusterBlockException when this metric reaches 0. To recover, you must either delete indices, add larger instances, or add EBS-based storage to existing instances.

Then you need to know how update-by-query works. Basically, it will reindex a new version of each document. So basically, if you ran the update on all your documents, ES has marked each of them as deleted when creating the new version. Deleted documents take space until a segment merge happens which will wipe all documents marked deleted, which is what you can observe each time the curve goes up again during the process.

In the end, it seems that the field you have copied has consumed 60K units of storage space (420K - 360K).

Comment: Understood now. Thank you @Val. I wonder why the last curve went up so high comparing to previous ones. Was that the final segment merge?

Comment: Segment merges happen all the time, but yes probably.